# How can I reassign the .Path parameter for objects in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that looks through folders in a directory for specific excel files based on that file's metadata. Because of the number of folders and files in the directory, the code runs for a long time before finishing. I have added a cancel key so I can cancel the macro. The code also writes the last path it was working on into sheet 1 of the workbook.

What I'm wanting to do is to have the code check if there is any value in sheet 1 where I have the path saved and update the subfolder path so that if I cancel the macro then I can later go back and start where I left off. However, when I attempt to reassign the .Path parameter I get a "Object variable or with block variable not set" error so I'm assuming it cannot be done this way.

My code is below:

```
Path = "C:\Users\blahblah\"
destination = "C:\Users\blahblah\blibbityblah\"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set obj_folder = FSO.GetFolder(Path)

On Error GoTo handleCancel
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
MsgBox "This may take a long time: press ESC to cancel"
For x = 1 To 1000000
    If Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
        obj_subfolder.Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
    End If
    For Each obj_subfolder In obj_folder.SubFolders
        For Each file In obj_subfolder.FILES
            Set oDetails = GetDetails(file.Path)
            If InStr(1, oDetails("Tags"), "EDGE") Then
                Call FSO.CopyFile(file.Path, FSO.BuildPath(destination, file.Name))0
            End If
        Next file
    Next obj_subfolder
Next x

handleCancel:
    If Err = 18 Then
        MsgBox "You cancelled"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = obj_subfolder.Path
    End If
End Sub
```

The block of code that I'm trying to implement but that is throwing the error is below:

```
If Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
    obj_subfolder.Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
End If
```

If there's a value in A1 on the worksheet then I want to alter the path of that subfolder to reflect what is in A1 just once. But I want it to stay within the loop so that the code doesn't try to go back and look through the folders I've already been through.

Comment: quick thought is to write each path to a hidden sheet as you process it; then have the code check the loop against the sheet and only process if the path isn't in the sheet....

Comment: You create an object `objFolder` but then you're trying to work with `objSubFolder`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks for your idea. I went that route.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value to the `Path` property of the `Folder` class.

Subfolders are returned in alphabetical order, as far as I can see. So, in the presence of a saved folder name, you could skip folder names until you find the saved one, as shown below.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoTheSubfolderThing()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Destination As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim obj_folder As Object
    Dim obj_subfolder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim cancelPath As String
    Dim proceed As Boolean
    Dim x As Long

    Path = "C:\Users\blahblah\"
    Destination = "C:\Users\blahblah\blibbityblah\"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set obj_folder = FSO.GetFolder(Path)

    On Error GoTo handleCancel

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    MsgBox "This may take a long time: press ESC to cancel"

    cancelPath = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value)
    proceed = (Len(cancelPath) = 0)

    For x = 1 To 1000000
        For Each obj_subfolder In obj_folder.SubFolders
            If Not proceed Then
                'Only proceed once we hit the saved folder name.
                proceed = (StrComp(obj_subfolder.Path, cancelPath, vbTextCompare) = 0)
            End If

            If proceed Then
                For Each file In obj_subfolder.Files
                    'Your code...
                    'Set oDetails = GetDetails(file.Path)
                    'If InStr(1, oDetails("Tags"), "EDGE") Then
                    '    Call FSO.CopyFile(file.Path, FSO.BuildPath(Destination, file.Name))
                    'End If
                Next file

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
            End If
        Next obj_subfolder
    Next x

handleCancel:
        If Err = 18 Then
            MsgBox "You cancelled"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = obj_subfolder.Path
        End If
End Sub
```

An assumption is that your external `For` loop is for illustrative purposes only. My code sample clears the saved path at a point that will make the inner loops scan all files after a first iteration over `x`, which may not be what you are trying to accomplish.